# Are there any Windows Mobile client/server file synchronization APIs?

Tags: windows-mobile, mobile, synchronization, windows-ce, activesync

MS has a good file/directory sync framework called Windows.Synchronization.Files, but it is not available for Mobile! Does anyone know what the standard way is of getting this functionality on Windows Mobile? I know ActiveSync allows you to transfer and sync files, but so far I haven't been able to find the API that they use for this. Is it open or is it a closed-source part of ActiveSync's services only?

Trying to avoid rolling my own. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out the new [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx).

Comment: The version available for Windows Mobile is the old one and does not have Microsoft.Synchronization.Files. The new one isn't for mobile (yet?).

Answer (score 0):

Sync is hard. So I would say your best bet is to use the Microsoft Sync Framework (as Rui said in his post) and write your own file sync provider.  You could then replace it at a later date with the newer v2 sync framework when it comes out.

Other options could be:

- Roll your own.  If you don't care about the thorner problems of sync then this could be quick and easy way.
- Use a [OMA](http://www.openmobilealliance.org/) based [SyncML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncML) client like the [Funambol](http://www.funambol.com/) [Windows Mobile client](https://www.forge.funambol.org/download/) (which I beleave supports files, but it's been awhile since I've looked).  It's nice in that the Funambol code is all Open Source.  It can make it easier to intergrate into your own product.  If you do a google search then you should be able to find lots of SyncML based clients.